# Can't open Tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat

I can't seem to open up the Tomcat console despite having *just* been able to successfully do so. When I click on the "startup" Windows Batch File, the console opens then closes itself immediately afterwards. I've read that it has something to do with setting up the environment variables / paths correctly but I've looked at it and it seems fine; you can check the picture out.

[image]NOTE: Over the course of step 6, the javac command did not work for me. To fix I added a second "C:\Program Files..jdk1.8.0_131\bin" into the Path variable (as you can see in the picture. This enabled me to use the javac command but I have no idea why it didn't detect the JAVA_HOME.

Trying to run startup via cmd console outputs the message: D:\myProject\tomcat\bin>startup
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

I'm still a beginner with server management so I've been following this tutorial: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html. I'm at the end of step 6c) where it tells me I should restart the server after compiling an servlet and creating an xml. But lo and behold, it won't open again after quitting...

Comment: Not sure if this changes anything but I have the JDK installed on my C drive while tomcat is located on my D drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not point JAVA_HOME to `bin` directory. Just point it to `jdk` directory, and add a `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `path` variable.